# vertx.createHttpServer() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, vert.x

I am playing a bit around with vertx.

Why does this code throws a NullPointerException?

```
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;

class vertxFacadeTest extends AbstractVerticle
{

    @Test
    void createServer()
    {
        HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
    }
}


java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.webinterface.vertxFacadeTest.createServer(vertxFacadeTest.java:23) //line 23 is this here: HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
```

Has anybody an idea why?
Looking forward :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Vertx` instance is null. Right now your class extends `AbstractVerticle`, which means that it has a `vertx` instance variable, but that is not initialized in its constructor; it's only set to a real value in the `AbstractVerticle.init()` method, which is only called by Vert.x when you deploy the Verticle. So in your case, when JUnit instantiates the class, `vertx` is null.

You shouldn't have the test class extend `AbstractVerticle`. Instead, create the `Vertx` instance explicitly in the test class, probably using a method annotated with `@Before`. See the documentation on Vert'x integration with JUnit [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/#_junit_integration).